# SQLite insert statement failing silently using Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm following along with the Flask/SQLite tutorial on the Flask website:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/sqlite3/

All of my select queries are working fine, but when I try an insert statement nothing happens. I get no error, but I also don't get an inserted row in my database. I'm not sure how to debug this when no error is happening. Does anyone have thoughts?

Here's my setup code:

```
def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)

@application.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = connect_db()

@application.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    if hasattr(g, 'db'):
        g.db.close()

def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
    cur = g.db.execute(query, args)
    rv = [dict((cur.description[idx][0], value)
               for idx, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv
```

Here's an example of a query that works:

```
@application.route('/api/galleries')
def get_galleries():
    query = query_db('select id, title, thumbnail from galleries')
    return json.dumps(query)
```

And here's my insert statement. This one does nothing, with no errors:

```
g.db.execute('insert into photos (is_favorite, galleries_id, filename) values (?, ?, ?)', [is_favorite, galleries_id, filename])
```

Comment: can you post your schema and the entire code for the view function that is trying to insert a row ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you committing after the INSERT?

```
g.db.execute('insert into photos (is_favorite, galleries_id, filename) values (?, ?, ?)', [is_favorite, galleries_id, filename])
g.db.commit()
```

Comment: I suspected that this might be the case but I couldn't find docs for it. I'll give that a go.

Comment: That was it. insert statements apparently must be explicitly committed before they're successful. Thank you Paul.

Comment: This just bit me too.  Problem was, the example at the python docs page for sqlite3 `execute()` statement doesn't mention commit after insert either (https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute ).  This is also a helpful idiom, I think, as the context manager will commit as it exits: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager

Comment: Wasted lots of time on this. Since my `create table` statements took effect without commit I assumed the connection auto commited on close.. Maybe a warning on should be issued if a connection is closed with pending transactions. Would be a bit noisy when a procedure fail (and it's expected that the connection should not commit) though.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer by @paul ...

From here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager

You can use a context manager (`with`) and it will commit on exit from the context:

```
with g.db:
    g.db.execute('insert into photos (is_favorite, galleries_id, filename) values (?, ?, ?)', [is_favorite, galleries_id, filename])
```

Also, at that link, you can see how to use that in conjunction with try/catch.